# Preventing Multiple Unintended PHP Form Submissions

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, form-submit

I run a website for a youth sports program that features schedules, standings, and score reporting using simple PHP scripts that manipulate data stored in a MySQL database.

After a game is played, the winning coach will access the score reporting form for that particular game, enter the information, and click submit to update the schedule and standings accordingly.  They are then automatically redirected to the schedule page that they came from.

However, several times a season, a coach will unintentionally duplicate a score submission (sometimes creating as many as three or four instances) which does not affect the result posted on the schedule, but does throw the data in the standings out of whack.  I'm not sure how exactly this is being accomplished, but I'm trying to fix the problem.

I've been reading up as much as possible on here and the web and believe that I need to implement some sort of token system to the reporting script, but I'm unsure how to exactly write the code?  Any advice here would be GREATLY appreciated.  Here is the script itself:

```
<?php

// Connect to the database:
require ('../mysqli_connect.php');

// Validate the school:
if (empty($_POST['school'])) {
echo "You forgot to enter your school.<br>";
$validate = 'false';
} elseif ($_POST['school'] != $_POST['away_team'] && $_POST['school'] != $_POST['home_team']) {
echo "Your school does not match one of the two on file for this game.<br>";
$validate = 'false';
} else {
$school = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['school']));
$validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the password:
if (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
echo "You forgot to enter your password.<br>";
$validate = 'false';
} else {
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['pass']));
$validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the away score:
if (!isset($_POST['away_score'])) {
echo "You forgot to enter the away score.<br>";
$validate = 'false';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['away_score'])) {
echo "You entered an invalid score for the away team.<br>";
$validate = 'false';
} else {
$away_score_confirm = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
$validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the home score:
if (!isset($_POST['away_score'])) {
echo "You forgot to enter the home score.<br>";
$validate = 'false';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['$home_score']) && $_POST['$home_score'] < 0 ) {
echo "You entered an invalid score for the home team.<br>";
$validate = 'false';
} else {
$home_score_confirm = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_score']));
$validate = 'true';
}

// Determine the winner and loser, and set variables:
if ($_POST['away_score'] > $_POST['home_score']) {
$winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_team']));
$winner_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
$loser = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_team']));
$loser_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_score']));
$tie = 'no';
} else if ($_POST['away_score'] < $_POST['home_score']) {
$winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_team']));
$winner_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_score']));
$loser = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_team']));
$loser_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
$tie = 'no';
} else if ($_POST['away_score'] == $_POST['home_score']) {
$tie = 'yes';
$tie1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_team']));
$tie2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_team']));
$tie_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
}

// Declare remaining hidden inputs as variables:
$league = $_POST['league'];
$table = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['table']);
$game_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['game_id']);
$sport = $_POST['sport'];

// Declare remaining hidden inputs as variables:
$standings_league = $table . "_standings";

// If all conditions are met, process the form:
if ($validate != 'false') {
$q1 = "SELECT school_id FROM user_schools WHERE (school_name='$school' AND pass='$pass')";
$r1 = mysqli_query($db, $q1);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($r1);
if ($num == 1) {
    // Get the game ID:
    $q2 = "SELECT $game_id FROM $table";
    $r2 = mysqli_query($db, $q2);
    // Get the row for the game ID:
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_NUM);
    // Perform an UPDATE query to modify the game scores:
    $q3 = "UPDATE $table SET home_score='$home_score_confirm', away_score='$away_score_confirm' WHERE game_id=$row[0]";        
    $r3 = mysqli_query($db, $q3);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 1) {
        $confirm = 'true';
    } else {
        $confirm = 'false';
    }

    // Update the winning team in the standings:
    $q4 = "SELECT school_id FROM $standings_league WHERE school_name='$winner'";
    $r4 = mysqli_query($db, $q4);
    // Get the row for the school:
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r4, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $q5 = "UPDATE $standings_league SET games=games + 1, win=win + 1, pts_for=pts_for + '$winner_score', pts_against=pts_against + '$loser_score' WHERE school_id=$row2[0]";
    $r5 = mysqli_query($db, $q5);
    $q6 = "UPDATE $standings_league SET pct=(win / games), avg_for=(pts_for / games), avg_against=(pts_against / games) WHERE school_id=$row2[0]";
    $r6 = mysqli_query($db, $q6);        

    // Update the losing team in the standings:
    $q7 = "SELECT school_id FROM $standings_league WHERE school_name='$loser'";
    $r7 = mysqli_query($db, $q7);
    // Get the row for the school:
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($r7, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $q8 = "UPDATE $standings_league SET games=games + 1, loss=loss+1, pts_for=pts_for + '$loser_score', pts_against=pts_against + '$winner_score' WHERE school_id=$row3[0]";
    $r8 = mysqli_query($db, $q8);
    $q9 = "UPDATE $standings_league SET pct=(win / games), avg_for=(pts_for / games), avg_against=(pts_against / games) WHERE school_id=$row3[0]";
    $r9 = mysqli_query($db, $q9);

    if ($confirm != 'false') {
        header('Location: schedules_' . $sport . '_' . $league . '.html?league=' . $league .'&table=' . $table);
    } else {
        echo "The scores could not be reported due to a system error. Apologies for the inconvenience. If this problem continues, please contact us directly.";
    }

} else {
    echo "Your school and password combination do not match those on file for this game.";
}       
}

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that these coaches are simply clicking the submit button multiple times while the form is waiting for a response from the server. You could use JS to disable (or hide) the button after the first click:

```
var button = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]'); // Use whatever selector is appropriate here

button.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (!button.classList.contains('submitting')) { // If this is our first click...
        button.className += ' submitting';
    } else { // Otherwise prevent submission
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

If you have jQuery available to you, you could also just handle the entire submission process via JS and block it there.

You should be aware of presenting some sort of feedback onto the screen to let the user know that a submission is currently in progress, that'll help alleviate some button mashing as well.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add a unique value to the form and when its submitted, add the value to a session. If they hit submit button more than once ( probably what is happening ), it will accept only one submition

Example:

```
<form>

  <input type="hidden" name="submit_id" value="<?php echo mt_rand(); ?>">

  // rest of the form

</form>
```

Php file recieving:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if ( isset( $_POST['submit_id'] ) ) {

    if ( !isset( $_SESSION['submit_id'] ) ) {
      $_SESSION['submit_id'] = array();
    } 

    if ( !in_array( $_POST['submit_id'], $_SESSION['submit_id'] ) ) {

      // validate posted values

      // when data is valid, register form as submitted
      $_SESSION['submit_id'][] = $_POST['submit_id'];

      // add the submitted form data to database

    }
    else {
      echo 'Your data has already been submitted';
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to read your code so I'll suggest a strategy.

I agree with @relic. Your coach is probably double-clicking the button.

If you can assume that different users will never submit two forms in the same second, then you can "filter" your table to accept only one entry for any given second. Make an index for the (new) seconds column, and make it unique. This will prevent insertions of rows to that table if an entry already exits for that second.

If this leads to conflicts, you can introduce restrictions that enforce every entry to be unique for a combination of other fields in the table. This is called compound keys (SQL). You formulate something like, for this game and user, there can only be one score registration.

MySQL:

```
create table scores (game_id int, user_id int, score int );
alter table scores add unique index uniq_gus (game_id, user_id, score);
insert into scores (game_id, user_id, score) values (1, 1, 10);
insert into scores (game_id, user_id, score) values (1, 1, 10);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1-10' for key 'uniq_gus'
```

In addition, you may want to prevent double-submissions (assuming jQuery):

```
(function($){

var btn =  $('button[type="submit"]');

btn.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    btn.attr('disabled','disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://foo.bar/form-endpoint.php',
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
           btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        },
    })
})

})(jQuery);
```